# combine query from multiple tables in django

Tags: python, django, orm

I get two tables, `data_table` and `old_data_table` for example, they contains exactly the same structure.

`data_table` contains only 1 month data. say from '2011-10-01' to now.
`old_data_table` contains the rest data.

Now if I have to query data between day '2011-09-01' to day '2011-10-07', is there a way to query it from both table and combine results in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't checked this code, but you'll want something like this...

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import chain

my_date = datetime.date(2011, 10, 1)
old_data = OldData.objects.filter(date_gte=my_date)
current_data = CurrentData.objects.filter(date_gte=my_date)
all_data = sorted(chain(old_data, new_data), key=lambda x: x.date)
```

Or you could check the documentation on raw sql queries.